# People can see web pages that are password protected how do I fix it

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Good morning all, I have a website that is for private users.  The user authenticates fine.  However all the pages after the login can be navigated to if the user knows the specific address. This can be done with out authenticating. How do I fix this, so that you need to be authenticated at all the times, to access this content.  I have created this web page in VB as an .ASP website.

Any help or suggestion would be very helpful.

Comment: Are you using ASP.NET MVC or WebForms?

Comment: IIS 6 or IIS 7 for hosting. It matters.

Comment: You'd have to give more info on your authentication scheme. Is it AD, database, etc???

Comment: `windows` auth or `forms` auth?

Comment: This is too broad of a question for stack overflow.  I suggest you start by studying the topic in greater detail to better understand how authentication should work.  http://www.asp.net/web-pages/tutorials/security/16-adding-security-and-membership

Comment: I am using a database, and I have set it up as a centralized auth method.  I will read the tutorial thanks for the link.

Answer (score 1):

Base on your input I think you are doing your authentication but are no setting your membership yet. You need to set your membership in the web.config file to set access to your sites only if a valid user is logged in.

Check this and I hope it gives you a better understanding of the process: [ASP memberships](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6e9y4s5t%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)